# How i improve the accuracy of image-based bacteria classifier

Tags: machine-learning, keras, image-processing

i'm new with ML. I am tring to develop a model that classifier bacteria by their staining properties. And i got 0.52 accuracy with my model.
İ have 223 images and 2 classes Gram Negative and Gram Positive

here is my code

```
dir = os.getcwd()
dataset_dir = os.path.join(dir,'Dataset')
Grampos_dir = os.path.join(dataset_dir,'GRAMPOS')
Gramneg_dir = os.path.join(dataset_dir,'GRAMNEG')




train_data_gen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,

        horizontal_flip=True,
        validation_split=0.1,
        channel_shift_range=10.0,

        rotation_range=0.4

                                                              )
train_set = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(
        dataset_dir,
        target_size=(256,256)
        ,color_mode='rgb',
        classes=(['GRAMNEG','GRAMPOS']),
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size= 1,
        subset='training'
        ,seed = 123

)
val_set = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(
        dataset_dir,
        target_size=(256,256)
        ,color_mode='rgb',
        classes=(['GRAMNEG','GRAMPOS']),
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=1,
        subset='validation'
        ,seed = 123,save_to_dir='/home/yusuf/Desktop/MİKROPROJECT/deneme'
)


model_check = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=os.path.join(dir,'ResNet50V2.hdf5'),save_best_only=True)
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=10)
basemodel = ResNet50V2(weights='imagenet',input_shape=(256,256,3),include_top=False)


model = Sequential()
model.add(basemodel)
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(train_set,epochs=50,validation_data=val_set,callbacks=[model_check,early_stop])
```

İ tried to change number of epoch and model but i got similar result. What else do you recommend to do ?

Comment: perhaps you can put your code on a colab - also add some pictures here. So it is easier for others to replicate your problem and beneficial for you to get what you want. if you don't care about your own problem nobody else does !

Comment: Try to visualize the training's history which reside in your history object to understand what's happening. Also you may want to reduce the data augmentation initially